# Parenthesis Matching F#

Tags: f#

So I am trying to use f# to find if a string has matching parentheses.
i.e: (abc) returns true, ((hello) returns false, and )( returns false, etc...

What I (think) am doing is using a stack to push when it sees a '(' and pop when it sees a ')' in the list. Then if the string list is empty, either the stack has an item or it doesn't. If it does, then I say that it is invalid, if I come across a ')' and the stack is empty, it is also invalid. Otherwise it is a valid string.

```
// Break string
let break_string (str:string) =
    Seq.toList str

let isBalanced (str:string) =
    let lst = break_string str
    let stack = []
    let rec balance str_lst (stk:'a list)= 
        match str_lst with
        | [] -> 
            if stk.Length > 0 then
                false
            else 
                true
        | x::xs -> 
            if x = '(' then
                balance (xs x::stack)
            elif x = ')' then
                if stack.Length = 0 then
                    false
                else
                    stack = stack.tail
    balance (lst, stack)
```

I am pretty new to f# so I think this might be doing what I want, however I get the error message:
"This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type 'a list -> bool"

First, what does that actually mean?
Second, since it is returning a bool, why doesn't that work?

Comment: @rpax, please stop adding useless tags

Comment: last call should be `balance lst stack`. That's how you call functions with multiple parameters in F#. `(a,b)` syntax creats a tuple. The same applies to recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type-checker thinks you forgot the second argument to `balance`. When you write this:

```
balance (xs x::stack)
```

It means "apply `balance` to (apply `xs` to `x::stack`)".  You probably meant this:

```
balance xs (x::stack)
```

Your final `elif` also seems to be missing an `else` branch, and the line `stack = stack.tail` looks like you're trying to assign to `stack`. You can't do that since `stack` is an immutable variable. Likely you want `balance xs (List.tail stack)`. The principle is that instead of assigning to variables, you call your function with new values.

---

You have the right idea, of course. It can be much more concise by folding all the matching (what's the letter? what's on the stack?) into one *single* match statement. The trick is to put all the things you want to look at into a single tuple:

```
let isBalanced str = 
    let rec loop xs stack = 
        match (xs, stack) with
        | '(' :: ys,  stack -> loop ys ('(' :: stack)
        | ')' :: ys, '(' :: stack -> loop ys stack
        | ')' :: _, _ -> false
        | _ :: ys, stack -> loop ys stack
        | [], [] -> true
        | [], _ -> false
    loop (Seq.toList str) []
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to have fixed that part; however, it is complaining about my  `elif = ')'` not being a bool? It says that it has uint.

Comment: Where is the `else` for that `elif`?

Comment: Oh, haha. That seems like a weird error for missing the else.

Comment: The reason why the error says it should be `unit` is because an `if` (or `elif`) without an `else` should necessarily have type `unit`.